# How to trace the called functions and executed statements of a C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, runtime, trace

I want to know how can I trace the execution of a C/C++ program during the running time? I am working on a new already existing code base, which is a large project. I want to run the project in a common use case, and I want to see which functions or methods get called during the running time. I want to run the C/C++ program, and be able to trace which functions, and which statements get executed in this specific use case.

I am familiar with strace and ltrace, which trace the execution of the program's system calls and library functions respectively. I am looking for something similar, but instead I want to see which functions of the project itself are executed during the running time of the program. Is there a specialized tool for that?

Alternatively, can I run the program in gdb without setting any breakpoints that would block the program so that it could run through in real time, and configure gdb to step into all the functions of the project, but not step into any library or system calls, and have gdb echo out all the functions that it steps into and all the statements that it executes into a log file?
I have the source code, and I can compile it with `-g -O0`.

Comment: FYI, there is no language `C/C++`.  C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` and C doesn't.  The C++ allows overloading of functions and operators, but C doesn't.  I recommend you replace "C/C++" in your post with the *single* language you are targeting.

Comment: If all you have is an executable then such tracing is often not possible, as (for example) release builds of executables generally don't contain information about what functions were in original source, so a debugger like gdb cannot relate instructions being executed to lines of code.   If you have the source code, it is possible to compile without optimisation (to prevent effects, such as the compiler reordering code or eliminating uncalled or inlined functions), embed debugging information, and then use a debugger to step through.

Comment: @Peter The thing is, I have the original source code, and compile it with `-g -O0`, but I don't want to step through the debugger, because this code represents a system that must run in real time. It cannot be blocked at a breakpoint. Statements must execute immediately one after another.

Answer (score 0):

-gp switch to gcc and gprof will help, but you'll need the source of your program to compile.

Comment: Please add more information. Tell me more about this.

Comment: @Galaxy: https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/programming/gprof.html  Note that there's only one `f` in `gprof`